# Swift LiteralConvertible not inferred in return type

Tags: swift

I'm 90% sure this is expected behaviour but in that case I'd just like to be educated!

In my project I've defined a temperature structure, conforming to the IntegerLiteralConvertible protocol:

```
struct Temperature {
    var kelvin: Int
    var celcius: Int { get { ... } }
    var fahrenheit: Int { get { ... } }
}

extension Temperature: IntegerLiteralConvertible {
    init(integerLiteral value: IntegerLiteralType) {
        kelvin = value
    }
}
```

Now everything works as I'd expect when creating an instance of temperature:

```
let absoluteZero: Temperature = 0
```

However if I return an `Int` in a function defined to return a `Temperature` i.e.

```
func randomTemperature() -> Temperature {
    return random()
}
```

I'll get the error message: "Cannot convert return expression of type 'Int' to return type 'Temperature'

Intuitively, I'd expect the returned type `Temperature` to be inferred from `Int` hence IntegerLiteralConvertible.

Digging around a bit in the docs (or now open source code :D!), I've found that the Int struct conforms to SignedNumberType which inherits from IntegerLiteralConvertible. I suspect that the answer to question lies in relation to that.

So, why?

Thanks in advance! (I'll keep digging around in the meantime)

Comment: `random()` is actually a built in function declared in "libkern.h"

The definition of it is `func random() -> Int`

Comment: I get the same error if I change `return random()` to `return Int(5)`, or any other Integer. `return arc4random_uniform(100)` gives the same error as well.

Comment: @jameslintaylor All you need to do is to initialise a Temperature object and return it. func randomTemperature() -> Temperature {
    return Temperature(integerLiteral: random())
}

Comment: Thanks Leo Dabus but part of the reason I'd like `Temperature` to conform to `IntegerLiteralConvertible` is for the ability to infer it's value without explicitly calling an initializer for it. In that case I could have just foregone the conformance to `IntegerLiteralConvertible` altogether and wrote an initializer `init(kelvin: Int)`. The current 'workaround' in my code does this already, in fact.

Comment: @jameslintaylor sorry for the delay, but my answer now should explain why you see the behaviour your describe. Your `Temperature` type does indeed conform to `IntegerLiteralConvertible`, and the error is one that is not specific to your type, but one of misunderstanding what a literal is (me too, I learned something! Good question).

Comment: Haha we, ahem, literally wrote the same answer pretty much at the same time! I've accepted yours of course. Thanks for the help!

Comment: plus 1 for your concise answer also. I (re-)learned something as well ;) Happy coding now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some discussion in the comments above, I realise what you want to ask is:

- Given the context of my struct including its extension, why does the `randomTemperature() -> Temperature` method fail when I try to to send an `int` value property as return type?

In code:

```
func randomTemperature() -> Temperature {
    let anyInt = 1
    return anyInt
        // Error: "Cannot convert return expression of 
        // type 'Int' to return type 'Temperature'
}
```

The short answer is: you cannot convert type 'Int' to return type `Temperature'` (as error states). What about your initialiser, you ask? The `Temperature: IntegerLiteralConvertible` init function `init(integerLiteral value: IntegerLiteralType)` only works on **literals** (`IntegerLiteralType`), and an integer is not a literal.

For a more thorough answer, see below.

---

From [Apple`s documentation on literals](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/LexicalStructure.html), it says

> A literal is the source code representation of a value of a type, such
>   as a number or string.
>
> ...
>
> **A literal doesn’t have a type on its own**. Instead, a literal is parsed as having infinite precision and Swift’s type inference
>   attempts to infer a type for the literal.
>
> ...
>
> When specifying the type annotation for a literal value, the
>   annotation’s type **must be a type that can be instantiated from that
>   literal value**. That is, the type must conform to one of the
>   following Swift standard library protocols:
>   *IntegerLiteralConvertible* for integer literals ...

And from Apple's documentation on the `IntegerLiteralConvertible` protocol:

> Conforming types can be initialized with integer literals.

Ok, so literal never have a type of their own. This sorts things out.

Consider, along the `Temperature` struct, the `Double` type, a type which also conforms to `IntegerLiteralConvertible`.

For `Double`, we have:

```
func someDouble() -> Double {
    return 1 // This is ok, "1" here is a literal, and the return
             // of type Double can be initialised via the literal
}

func someDoubleTrouble() -> Double {
    let anyInt = 1
    return anyInt // Error! anyInt is not a literal, but an Int type,
                  // and return typ expects Double (or literal).
}

// The same applies for these
var someInt = 1
var anotherDouble: Double = 1 // ok, as above, literal
var anotherDoubleTrouble: Double = someInt // Error!
```

Exactly the same applies for your `Temperature` struct type.

```
func someTemperature() -> Temperature {
    return 1 // Ok
}

func someTroubledTemperature() -> Temperature {
    let myInt = 1
    return myInt // Error!
}

// The same applies for these
var someInt = 1
var anotherTemperature: Temperature = 1 // ok, as above, literal
var anotherTroubledTemperature: Temperature = someInt // Error!
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that I've fundamentally misunderstood the type system in Swift. In the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_IntegerLiteralConvertible_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/intfctr/IntegerLiteralConvertible/s:FPSs25IntegerLiteralConvertiblecuRq_S__FMq_FT14integerLiteralqq_S_18IntegerLiteralType_q_) for `IntegerLiteralConvertible` and symmetrically among other 'LiteralConvertible' types is:

> "Conforming types can be initialized with integer literals."

A literal, in programming is typically a constant defined in source code. Straight from the [Swift language guide docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/LexicalStructure.html):

> "A literal is the source code representation of a value of a type, such as a number or string."

As such, I now know why my `Temperature` type cannot be initialized with an `Int` as, rather than an integer literal, an `Int` is just a struct in itself conforming to the `IntegerLiteralConvertible` protocol. It appears that the 'convertibility' does not happen both ways (or at least is not inferred dynamically by the syntax analyzer).